# Laravel Redirect to view after data save

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I have created a form and  inserted form values to database successfully using laravel 5.3. But after submit data i can't redirect to view page it shows a blank page . below is my code

**View(store.blade.php):**

```
{{Form::open(array('action' => 'Testing@store', 'method' => 'post'))}}

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('title', 'Title:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
    {!! Form::text('title', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('description', 'Description:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
        {!! Form::textarea('description', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>

    {!! Form::submit('Submitform', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}

    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

**Controller(Testing.php):**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\curd;
class testing extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('pages.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

      $storeform=new curd();
      $storeform->savemodel($request);


    }
}
```

**Model (curd.php):**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use DB;
class curd extends Model
{
    public function savemodel($request)
    {
     // $request->input('title');
     DB::table('tset')->insert(
             ['heading' => $request->input('title'),'description'=>$request->input('description')]
             ); 

      return redirect()->back();


    }
}
```

I don't know how to redirect after form submit from model.Please help me

Comment: You are redirecting in model. It is not acceptable. It should be handled in controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dont do you're redirect on your model. Move return redirect()->back() to your store-method instead.